# VMWARE ESXI 7.0.1 don't recognize RAM installed after upgrade

Tags: memory, virtualization, vmware, esxi, vmware-server

I have a Oracle Server X6-2 ESXi 7, I installed with two(2)x32Gb ram DDR4(for 64 in total), but recently I upgrade the server to 128GB, with other 2x32 Gb modules. The BIOS and ILOX recognize the memory:
[ILO show good installed memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CUKU.png)
But Vmware ESXi dont recognize the memory! :o
[ESXi7with128Gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ07y.png)

What can i do?

Comment: 1)Are you using a free or expired license (evaluation mode)? Many times a free license has limitations, however [this PDF from vmware (pg8)](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/products/vsphere/vmware-vsphere-pricing-whitepaper.pdf) indicates there is no RAM limitations. 2)Did you upgrade from an earlier version? You might have more success on [serverfault](serverfault.com) as this is kind of a professional product

Comment: You might want to provide the page from the manual that indicates which DDR4 slots are for which processor and specify which slots you installed the modules in (and the specific part numbers)

Comment: 3)On host, [F2, 'View System Information' or 'View System Logs'](https://core.vmware.com/resource/standalone-esxi-installation-and-configuration) show any info about RAM? 4)In the F2 'Customize' can you 'Reset System Configuration'? 5)Can you reinstall ESXi? The [server is verified as its in their Compatibility Guide](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=server&productid=41056&vcl=true)

Comment: [@Ramhound question](https://superuser.com/questions/1725839/vmware-esxi-7-0-1-dont-recognize-ram-installed-after-upgrade#comment2666749_1725839) is likely the culprit, if the system has one CPU you can only install RAM in the `P0` slots. Based on your picture you installed it two sticks in `P1` RAM slots which won't work without a second CPU. [Oracle page on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E62159_01/html/E62171/z40003f01425459.html#scrolltoc)

Comment: The server have 2 CPU